# Heroku deployment error via codeship

Tags: heroku, codeship

I want to deploy django app to heroku via codeship and it generate an error and that is `wget -O/dev/null http://something.herokuapp.com`
How to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marko from the Codeship team here. Could you paste some more log output, or open a ticket on https://helpdesk.codeship.com?

Judging from the command you pasted above, I'd guess the check if the Heroku app, that you just deployed to, is running fails and this causes the build itself to fail.

Without any additional configuration we check the root URL for your application at `http://HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com` via `wget` and see if it returns an HTTP/2xx or HTTP/3xx status code.

If it does, the check succeeds, else the build fails.

You can take a look at the script we use to perform the check at https://github.com/codeship/scripts/blob/master/utilities/check_url.sh

Comment: Problem was in my uWSGI settings. Thanks for support.